# Admob ads don't show up

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, ads, banner-ads

I have 3 apps with banner ads, but they worked fine just for 3 days, then stopped to show, this is happing for almost 15 days. In my admob account it's everything right, then I checked my log, and what I get is this:

E/chromium(12906): [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
I/Ads     (12906): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (12906): Ad with id `null` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.